Applying Paging using Offset & Limit i got that a column does not exists
I have this formula inside power bi to get data from external Api:-
let
body=Text.Combine({"sAPIKey=",ApiKey}),
SourceAPILogin=Json.Document(
Web.Contents(
SmartAPI,
[
RelativePath="apilogin",
Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",#"API-Key"=Token],
Content=Text.ToBinary(body)
]
)
),
tblGetUID = Table.FromList(SourceAPILogin, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
expGetUID = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(tblGetUID, "Column1", {"UID", "LanguageCode", "DatabaseVersion"}, {"Column1.UID", "Column1.LanguageCode", "Column1.DatabaseVersion"}),
GetUID = expGetUID{0}[Column1.UID],
Source=Json.Document(
Web.Contents(
SmartAPI,
[
RelativePath = "jobs", //RESTAPI endpoint
//Query = [#"sQueryKey" = QueryKey,#"FilterLocation"="Database"], // QueryParameters
Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/json",#"API-Key"=Token, UID=GetUID, DeviceID=ApiKey] //Headers
]
)
),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
//display all the columns from query
Result=Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table","Column1", Table.ColumnNames(Table.FromRecords(List.Select(Table.Column(#"Converted to Table","Column1"), each _ <> "" and _ <> null))),Table.ColumnNames(Table.FromRecords(List.Select(Table.Column(#"Converted to Table","Column1"), each _ <> "" and _ <> null)))),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Result,{{"StartedDate", type datetime}})

in
#"Changed Type"

currently i am only getting 10,000 items, so I wanted to apply paging using offset & limit, so I modified the code as follow:-
let
    // Function to fetch data with pagination
    Fetchjobs = (Offset as number, Limit as number) as table =>
        let
            body = Text.Combine({"sAPIKey=", ApiKey}),
            SourceAPILogin = Json.Document(
                                Web.Contents(
                                    SmartAPI,
                                    [
                                        RelativePath="apilogin",
                                        Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",#"API-Key"=Token],
                                        Content=Text.ToBinary(body)
                                    ]
                                )
                            ),
            tblGetUID = Table.FromList(SourceAPILogin, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
            expGetUID = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(tblGetUID, "Column1", {"UID", "LanguageCode", "DatabaseVersion"}, {"Column1.UID", "Column1.LanguageCode", "Column1.DatabaseVersion"}),
            GetUID = expGetUID{0}[Column1.UID],
            Source = Json.Document(
                        Web.Contents(
                            SmartAPI,
                            [
                                RelativePath = "jobs",
                                Query = [#"offset"=Text.From(Offset), #"limit"=Text.From(Limit)], // Adding Offset and Limit parameters
                                Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/json",#"API-Key"=Token, UID=GetUID, DeviceID=ApiKey] 
                            ]
                        )
                    ),
            tblAll = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
            tableHasRecords = Table.RowCount(tblAll) > 0,
            Result = if tableHasRecords then
                        Table.ExpandRecordColumn(tblAll,"Column1", Table.ColumnNames(Table.FromRecords(List.Select(Table.Column(tblAll,"Column1"), each _ <> "" and _ <> null))),Table.ColumnNames(Table.FromRecords(List.Select(Table.Column(tblAll,"Column1"), each _ <> "" and _ <> null))))
                     else
                        #table(Table.ColumnNames(tblAll), {})
        in
            Result,

    // Initial pagination parameters
    Offset = 0,
    Limit = 10000,
    PageSize = 10000,

    // Loop through pages to get all records
    AllPages = List.Generate(
                    () => [Result = Fetchjobs(Offset, Limit), Offset = Offset + PageSize],
                    each Table.RowCount([Result]) > 0,
                    each [Result = Fetchjobs([Offset], Limit), Offset = [Offset] + PageSize],
                    each [Result]
                ),

    // Combine all the pages into a single table
    tbljobs = Table.Combine(AllPages),

    // Change column types as needed
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(tbljobs,{{"StartedDate", type datetime}})
    
in
    #"Changed Type"

but after applying the offset &limit I got this error:-

Expression.Error: The column 'StartedDate' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
StartedDate


here is the API i am trying to connect to @ https://developer.smarttid.dk/smartapi/jobs
Also if I remove the column transform, as follow:-
let
    // Function to fetch data with pagination
    Fetchjobs = (Offset as number, Limit as number) as table =>
        let
            body = Text.Combine({"sAPIKey=", ApiKey}),
            SourceAPILogin = Json.Document(
                                Web.Contents(
                                    SmartAPI,
                                    [
                                        RelativePath="apilogin",
                                        Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",#"API-Key"=Token],
                                        Content=Text.ToBinary(body)
                                    ]
                                )
                            ),
            tblGetUID = Table.FromList(SourceAPILogin, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
            expGetUID = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(tblGetUID, "Column1", {"UID", "LanguageCode", "DatabaseVersion"}, {"Column1.UID", "Column1.LanguageCode", "Column1.DatabaseVersion"}),
            GetUID = expGetUID{0}[Column1.UID],
            Source = Json.Document(
                        Web.Contents(
                            SmartAPI,
                            [
                                RelativePath = "jobs",
                                Query = [#"offset"=Text.From(Offset), #"limit"=Text.From(Limit)], // Adding Offset and Limit parameters
                                Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"Content-Type"="application/json",#"API-Key"=Token, UID=GetUID, DeviceID=ApiKey] 
                            ]
                        )
                    ),
            tblAll = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
            tableHasRecords = Table.RowCount(tblAll) > 0,
            Result = if tableHasRecords then
                        Table.ExpandRecordColumn(tblAll,"Column1", Table.ColumnNames(Table.FromRecords(List.Select(Table.Column(tblAll,"Column1"), each _ <> "" and _ <> null))),Table.ColumnNames(Table.FromRecords(List.Select(Table.Column(tblAll,"Column1"), each _ <> "" and _ <> null))))
                     else
                        #table(Table.ColumnNames(tblAll), {})
        in
            Result,

    // Initial pagination parameters
    Offset = 0,
    Limit = 10000,
    PageSize = 10000,

    // Loop through pages to get all records
    AllPages = List.Generate(
                    () => [Result = Fetchjobs(Offset, Limit), Offset = Offset + PageSize],
                    each Table.RowCount([Result]) > 0,
                    each [Result = Fetchjobs([Offset], Limit), Offset = [Offset] + PageSize],
                    each [Result]
                ),

    // Combine all the pages into a single table
    tbljobs = Table.Combine(AllPages)//,

    // Change column types as needed
    //#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(tbljobs,{{"StartedDate", type datetime}})
    tbljobs
in
    tbljobs//#"Changed Type"

I will not get any result from the table.
So what could be the issue?
Thanks

Have you tried diagnosing with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/query-diagnostics?

My guess is that the server is returning JSON results that, rather than explicitly stating that StartedDate is null, StartedDate is missing/omitted from JSON objects where it's null.
Therefore, when PowerQuery converts JSON to a table and doesn't see any StartedDate properties within an entire page of data, the resulting table doesn't have a StartedDate column!
Try creating a function that combines tables of dissimilar column names, like so...
(Tables as list) as table =>
let
    #"Column names per table" = List.Transform(Tables, Table.ColumnNames),
    AllColumnNames = List.Distinct(List.Combine(#"Column names per table")),
    #"Missing column names per table" = List.Transform(#"Column names per table", each List.RemoveItems(AllColumnNames, _)),
    #"Tuples of table & missing column names" = List.Zip({Tables, #"Missing column names per table"}),
    #"Tables with all column names" = List.Transform(
        #"Tuples of table & missing column names",
        each List.Accumulate(
            _{1}, // Missing column names
            _{0}, // Table
            (tbl, cn) => Table.AddColumn(tbl, cn, each null)
        )
    ),
    Combined = Table.Combine(#"Tables with all column names")
in
    Combined

If I'm right, and if you put that in a separate query named fTableCombineWithColumnsCheck then you can replace tbljobs = Table.Combine(AllPages) with tbljobs = fTableCombineWithColumnsCheck(AllPages) and things will start working.

will try this and keep you posted
